# Unable to rewrite the URL from "login" to "login.php" using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a server which hosts a few sites. On one site, I can use the rewrite engine through `.htaccess` like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^avy.png avy/avy.php
```

`/avy.png` works fine on the first site.
On the second site, however, I'm using rewrite engine in `.htaccess` like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^login login.php
```

And when visiting `/login`, it shows me a 404. `/login.php` works fine.

The two sites have virtually the same vhost config (only difference is `ServerName`). `/login.php` allows world to read it. Both sites are http only. I'm using CloudFlare for both sites. What could the issue be?

Comment: .htaccess might not be enabled on 2nd site.

Comment: The other lines in the .htaccess work fine

Comment: Is the 404 from Cloudflare or from your site? I don't 100% understand the Cloudflare system.

Comment: Can you try: `RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php [L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an error in the log... seems it only appeared just now.

```
Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /srv/http/.../login (None could be negotiated)
```

I googled it, and apparently MultiViews was conflicting with my extension-less "login" string. Turned off multiviews and it works perfectly.